# Ocultar y Mostrar div desde una función JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Quisiera una función `JavaScript` que me oculte una división si el Scroll está en el tope y de lo contrario la oculte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este snippet te puede servir:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 100) {
    $('.topMenu').fadeOut();
  } else {
    $('.topMenu').fadeIn();
  }
});
```

Te lo comparto funcionando:

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 100) {
    $('.topMenu').fadeOut();
  } else {
    $('.topMenu').fadeIn();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
    height:1600px;
}
.topMenu {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    background: lightgray;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topMenu"></div>
```

Comment: Muy bueno ...resulto gracias